# What is the best practice to start "roscore" followed by "rosrun ...." on Docker Container startup?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, ubuntu-18.04, ros

I have created through a Dockerfile a Docker image on which Ubuntu 18.04 and ROS Melodic are properly installed. Please note that I have not used the [official ROS-Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/ros) for creating my Docker image.

The Docker container derived from this Docker image is working fine.
However, every time I want to work with the container, I need to execute the following commands:

1. Terminal window:

`docker run -d -it --name container_name docker_image; docker exec -it container_name bash`

Then, after I am within the Docker container:
`roscore`

2. Terminal window:

`docker exec -it container_name bash`

Then, after I am within the Docker container:
`rosrun ROS_PackageName PythonScript.py`

Please note that through the above-mentioned Docker commands, both terminals operate in the **same** Docker container.

I find my way to start the PythonScript.py inefficient.
Therefore, I would like to ask for the best practice to start "roscore" followed by "rosrun ...." on Docker Container startup.

In some Dockerfiles I see at the end of the file the command `ENTRYPOINT` as well as `CMD`.
However, I do not know if these commands can help me to make my Docker container execute "roscore" followed by "rosrun" on container startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually, in part, what [roslaunch](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch) is for. It makes it easier to launch multiple nodes and nicer parameter input, but it will *also* start a `roscore` is one is not already running. In your example it would look something like this:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="ROS_PackageName" type="PythonScript.py" name="my_node_name" output="screen" >
  </node>
</launch>
```

When running `roslaunch` via CLI you would use it the same way you would `rosrun`. For example if you create the launch file in the same example package you listed and named the file `my_launch.launch` the command would look like: `roslaunch ROS_PackageName my_launch.launch`. Simply replace the `rosrun` command above with this.

Comment: Great idea! With which command within the Dockerfile can I execute the roslaunch-script after Docker Container startup?

Comment: @Coding4Fun I've edited my answer to provide info as to how you would use `roslaunch` instead of `rosrun`